# Forward production http request to staging server

Tags: apache, tomcat, tee, web-traffic

I would like to find a nice way to route all my production http traffic temporarly to a staging server (equivalent to the production) to be able to monitor it.

How can I do that (we use apache / tomcat 7), but any solution might be helpful as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to solve this at the network layer by having a low level load balancer / ip sprayer in front of these instances and being able to cut over to one in an active/passive manner.

DNS is another alternative way to subvert some/all of the traffic after a period of time.